# Sort products by custom meta key in Woocommerce archives

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I want to sorting product by discount percentage by high to low or low to high. I am using urna theme but sorting not working properly. I want it discount percentage wise if discount percentage same it will show price high to low or low to high. I using more sorting plugins. But its not working properly. Kindly help this. I am a beginner in woocommerce.
Please help

My code

```
    <?php


add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_ordering_args' );
function mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'discount' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order']      = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key']   = '_dfrps_salediscount';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby' );
function mycode_woocommerce_add_salediscount_to_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['discount']     = 'Sort by discount';
    return $sortby;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just want help how to use sorting discount

Comment: I add the code but its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'enable_catalog_ordering_by_meta' );
function enable_catalog_ordering_by_meta( $args ) {
    $meta_key = '_dfrps_salediscount';

    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        if ( 'custom_meta1' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array(
                'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
                'meta_key' => $meta_key,
            );
        }
        // Make a clone of "menu_order" (default option)
        elseif ( 'natural_order' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array( 'orderby'  => 'menu_order title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        }
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_catalog_orderby_by_meta' );
function add_catalog_orderby_by_meta( $orderby_options ) {
    // Insert "Sort by product reference (sku)" and the clone of "menu_order"
    return array(
        'custom_meta1'  => __("Sort by discount", "woocommerce");
        'natural_order' => __("Sort by natural order", "woocommerce"), // <== To be renamed at your convenience
    ) + $orderby_options ;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'default_catalog_orderby_meta' );
function default_catalog_orderby_meta( $default_orderby ) {
    return 'custom_meta1';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'product_query_by_meta' );
function product_query_by_meta( $q ) {
    $meta_key = '_dfrps_salediscount';
    
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && ! is_admin() ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        $q->set( 'meta_key', $meta_key);
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: adding above code in shop page no product found. Already we have 5000 products

Comment: @T.K A similar code works for "_sku" meta key in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275842/3730754) I made… I cant help anymore than that, sorry.

Comment: Any other way to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.Add this code in cureent active theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'vzm_product_query_by_meta' );
function vzm_product_query_by_meta( $q ) {
   $meta_key = 'staff_pick';   //your-meta key
   if ( ! isset( $_GET['orderby'] )) {
      $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );   // for numeric value
      $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
      $q->set( 'meta_key', $meta_key);
   }
}
```